# Ошибка в запросе: ORA-00904: недопустимый идентификатор

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Есть запрос:

```
with eq as
 (select pe.equipment_id as id,
         row_number() over(order by pe.equipment_id) as rn
    from metrology.protocol_equipment pe
   where pe.protocol_id = :protocol_id
     and pe.pr_eq_type = 1)
select (select (select asu_tp_iis_system_id from metrology.v_equipment_info e where e.id = eq.id) from eq where rn = 1) as asu_tp_iis_system_id,
       (select (select (select d.short_name from metrology.department d where d.id = e.department_id) from metrology.equipment e where e.id = eq.id) from eq where rn = 1) as department_name,
       (select metrology.pkg_equipment.GetEquipmentDocs(eq.id, 1, 0, 1) from eq where rn = 1) as control_doc,
       decode(p.dic_control_type_id, 1, 'ïîâåðêè', 2, 'êàëèáðîâêè') as dic_control_type,
       decode(p.dic_control_type_id, 1, 'Ïîâåðêà', 2, 'Êàëèáðîâêà') as dic_control_type1,
       decode(p.dic_control_type_id, 1, 'ïîâåðêå', 2, 'êàëèáðîâêå') as dic_control_type2,
       decode(p.dic_control_type_id, 1, 'Ïîâåðêó âûïîëíèë', 2, 'Êàëèáðîâêó âûïîëíèë') as dic_control_type3,
       decode(p.dic_control_type_id, 1, 'ïðèãîäíîñòè ÒC ' , 2, 'ñîîòâåòñòâèè äåéñòâèòåëüíûõ çíà÷åíèé ÒC òðåáîâàíèÿì ÍÄ') as dic_control_type4,
       case when p.control_type in (1,2,4,5) then 'ïåðâè÷íîé'
            when p.control_type = 3 then 'ïåðèîäè÷åñêîé'
            else ''
       end as control_type,
       doc.doc_num,
       doc.doc_date,
       metrology.utl_system.DateToChar(doc.doc_date) as doc_date_char,
       p.metrology_user_id,
       (select metrology.pkg_dics.GetCompanyName('long') from dual) as long_company_name,
       (select metrology.pkg_equipment.GetEquipmentDocsCode(eq.id, 1, 0, 1) from eq where rn = 1) as control_doc_code
  from metrology.protocol p 
  join metrology.doc on doc.id = p.doc_id
 where p.doc_id = :protocol_id
```

И в данной строке:

```
(select metrology.pkg_equipment.GetEquipmentDocsCode(eq.id, 1, 0, 1)
 from eq where rn = 1) as control_doc_code
```

возникает ошибка:

> ORA-00904: недопустимый идентификатор

С чем может быть связана проблема, и может она быть заключена в выполняемой функции?

Comment: В какой "данной строке" и главное, приведите сообщение об ошибке целиком, в нем же явно сказано какой идентификатор ему не нравится. А вообще если ругается значит этого нет в базе или нет прав  на это

Comment: Прошу прощения, намудрил с тегами. В данной строке (select metrology.pkg_equipment.GetEquipmentDocsCode(eq.id, 1, 0, 1) from eq where rn = 1) as control_doc_code

Comment: В функции она маловероятна. Скорее всего она не видит самой функции (ее нет или нет прав на нее).

Comment: Кстати подзапрос в with (с учетом использования rn=1) эквивалентен           `select min(equipment_id) from metrology.protocol_equipment where protocol_id = :protocol_id and pr_eq_type = 1`

Comment: Методом половинного деления убирай операторы и найди на каком месте ругается.

Answer (score 2):

Ошибка:

> ORA-00904: %s: недопустимый идентификатор

возникает, если идентификатор в запросе незнаком SQL парсеру по причине того, что он не сушествует, или он не видим в текушей схеме из-за недостатка привилегий.

Но самая частая причина этой ошибки - несоответствие регистра имени идентификатора из-за объявление его с двойными кавычками.

В сообщении об ошибке указывается, какой идентификатор и в какой строке не найден.  Достаточно выполнить только часть запроса, на которую указывает ошибка:

```
create table me.eq ("Id") as
    select 1 from dual;

create or replace package me.pack as
    function "getSomething" (par int) return int;
end;
/
create or replace package body me.pack as
    function "getSomething" (par int) return int is
    begin
        execute immediate 'select "Id" from me.eq';
        return par;
    end;
end;
/

select me.pack.getSomething (eq.Id) from me.eq
```

> ORA-00904: "ME"."PACK"."GETSOMETHING": недопустимый идентификатор

Здесь надо заметить:

- `"GETSOMETHING"` и `"getSomething"` это разные имена идентификаторов.
- Эта ошибка может возникнуть в функции *только*, если там есть динамический запрос. Статические запросы проверяются во время компиляции.

Начинаем исправлять:

```
select me.pack."getSomething" (eq.Id) from me.eq
/
ORA-00904: "EQ"."ID": недопустимый идентификатор

select me.pack."getSomething" (eq."Id") from me.eq
/
ORA-00904: "ID": недопустимый идентификатор
ORA-06512: на  "ME.PACK", line 4

--"ME.PACK" в 4 строке: execute immediate 'select "Id" from me.eq'; 

select me.pack."getSomething" (eq."Id") from me.eq
/
ME.PACK."GETSOMETHING"(EQ."ID")
-------------------------------
                              1
```

Answer (score 1):

Возможно так:

```
(select metrology.pkg_equipment.GetEquipmentDocsCode(eq.id, 1, 0, 1) from eq where eq.rn = 1) as control_doc_code
```

Comment: Возможно, но скорее всего нет.